# simulate vectors as 2D arrays

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, vector, 2d-vector

I know that we can't have multi dimensional vectors. But I thought about defining the cells of the vector as pointers and this way simulate a two dimensional vector. Here's the code:

```
const char* filename = "D:\\desktop\\IP_ABAD\\images\\1.png";  
GDALDataset  *poDataset = NULL ;  
GDALAllRegister();

poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( filename, GA_ReadOnly );
const int RasterXSize = poDataset -> GetRasterXSize();
const int RasterYSize = poDataset -> GetRasterYSize();
const int RasterCount = poDataset -> GetRasterCount();
CPLErr error = CE_None;
GDALRasterBand *poRasterBand; 
poRasterBand = poDataset -> GetRasterBand(1);
GDALDataType eType;
eType = poRasterBand -> GetRasterDataType();
int nbpp = GDALGetDataTypeSize(eType) / 8;
vector<unsigned char> data(RasterXSize * RasterYSize * RasterCount * nbpp);
error = poDataset -> RasterIO(GF_Read,0,0,RasterXSize,RasterYSize,&data[0],RasterXSize,RasterYSize,eType,RasterCount,0,0,0,0);
vector<unsigned char*>SeperateBitsBands(RasterCount * nbpp);
int sizeOfData = (int)data.size();
int sizeOfSeperateBitsBands = (int)SeperateBitsBands.size();
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeOfSeperateBitsBands ; i++)
{
   for ( int j = 0 ; j < sizeOfData ; j++ )
   {
       if (j%sizeOfSeperateBitsBands == i)
       {
           SeperateBitsBands[i]-> pushback(data.at(j));
       }
   }
}
```

But in the line `SeperateBitsBands[i]-> pushback(data.at(j));` I get the errors:

```
IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-class type
error C2227: left of '->pushback' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

In this code at first I have opened an image and extract its digital numbers by `RasterIO` function from the 'GDAL library`. Of course RasterIO reads the image sequentially so I have tried to seperate parts of the image with the help of two nested for loops.
For example suppose that the image is an RGB one (have three bands) with bit depth of 16 and size 300x400 then seperatedBitsBands would be a vector with size 6 each cell pointing to a vector with 120000 size.
last day I had a code like this:

```
vector<GDALRasterBand*>Bands(RasterCount);  
for ( i = 0; i<RasterCount; i++)
{
    Bands.at(i) -> RasterIO(..............)  
}
```

But I didn't have such an error in the line `Bands.at(i) -> RasterIO(..............)`.
Could anyone tell me either I can do something like this?( I mean simulate a 2D vector ). If so,how???
And why i didn't have the error in the `Bands.at(i) -> RasterIO(..............)`???
**And the most important does using multi dimensional vectors influence alot on the performance and speed?**
Thanks alot.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you actually need? You can have 2D vectors, but usually you are better off with a wrapper around a single vector or array, which provides 2D access via two indices.

Comment: @juanchopanza I actually need high preformance because of working with high resolution .tiff images. you said: `single vector or array, which provides 2D access via two indices`? How can I implement it? it would be appreciated if you give some links

Answer (score 2):

> I know that we can't have multi dimensional vectors

You **can** have 2D vectors like:

```
vector< vector<char> > SeperateBitsBands;
```

**Please note** :While declaring a vector of vectors, be careful not to put two > together as follows:

```
vector<vector<char>> SeperateBitsBands;
```

as this **>>** would be mistaken for a right shift operator by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @thomas and how I will declare size of vector?

Comment: @sepideh Look at [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), see the "constructors" section.

Comment: @sepideh: Vectors don't have fixed sizes. You can `resize` them or push stuff at their back. However, you can specify their *initial* size like this: `vector<vector<int>> a (10, vector<int>(20));` which defines a 10x20 matrix (10 vectors that have 20 elements each.)

Comment: so @yzt if I would like to have a 3d vector, the declaration will be as: 'vector<vector<vector<int>>>a(10,vector<vector<int>>(20,vector<int>(30))`right? so 2 questions rose up   1- can i index these vectors just like multidim arrays and how to push back a character at the end of them? 2-Does using multi dim vectors influence alot on the performance?

Comment: `>>` is perfectly fine in C++11.

Comment: so @juanchopanza a question is what is the difference between boost::multiarray and multi dimentional vector for example from the performance and running speed point of view?

Comment: oh ok boost is a 3rd party library

Comment: @sepideh: You will index these exactly like normal arrays; e.g. `a[i][j][k]` for a 3D vector-of-vectors-of-vectors. And, you do something like `a[i][j].push_back(42);` or `a[i].push_back(vector<int>(7, 0));` which adds a vector of seven integers (and set them all to zero) to the *i*th 2D vector in the 3D vector. Performance-wise, it's the same as using an `int *** a;` and `new`ing all the dimensions separately. Also, remember that all the dimensions' sizes are independent from each other (it's not really a matrix, but a vector of vectors that can have different lengths.)

Comment: @sepideh: Oh, and if you want best performance, you can use C++11's `std::array` (instead of `std::vector`) which has static size and therefore is better laid-out in memory (the same as static C arrays) and absolutely no overhead.

Comment: well thanks @yzt but how can I use C++11 and how can I use it in visual studio 2010?

Comment: @sepideh: You can't (in VC10.) Sorry! Unless Boost (or another 3rd-party library) has an implementation (I don't know if it does.) I suggest that you use vector. It's more flexible and the performance only differs in certain very rare use-cases and even then it won't be a problem or even noticeable in the vast majority of applications. In short, use `std::vector`!

Comment: thanks @yzt but when [I implemented the code with the help of 3D vectors for a LandSat image the computer crashed down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630185/any-suggestion-to-enhance-the-performance-of-code-which-works-with-high-resoluti) so can you tell me which one boost,c++11 arrays and vector have a higher performance? Do I need to install a later release of VISUAL STUDIO to use C++11 feature? Or maybe it's better to use one block inde4xing as said [here?](http://www.eld.leidenuniv.nl/~moene/Home/tips/matrix2d/)I mean do you think 1d vector would have alot higer performance?

Comment: Notice that my computer crashed down so I need a big higher performance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33426/discussion-between-yzt-and-sepideh)